# Is there a way to scatter/cross plot blocks of two larger 2D arrays and obtain the gradient/slope between the two?

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, linear-regression, gradient

I have two matrices (2D arrays) with identical shapes, but holds different values. I want to split the matrices into smaller sub-matrices, then scatter plot the values in each sub-matrix and extract the gradient from the regression line in each plot.

I have managed to split the matrices, but i can't access and plot the sub-matrices and extract their gradient.

The final result I want to obtain is a plot of the gradient values from each sub-matrix.

Comment: What programming language are you using? Can you share a concise example of the code that you're having trouble with?

Comment: Python. I havnt started on it yet because I dont know what to do..

Comment: Would you please post a link to the data?